# Semigroup generation

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be Hilbert space of the vectors $f = \left(%
\begin{array}{c}
  f^{+}(x) \\
  f^{-}(x) \\
\end{array}%
\right)$ where $f^{+}(x),$ $f^{-}(x)$ belong to the class
$L^{2}(-1,1)$ of the functions which are square integrable on
$(-1,1)$. The scalar product of two elements $f$, $g \in
\mathcal{H}$ is defined by$$\displaystyle{<f,g> =
\int_{-1}^{1}\left[f^{+}(x)g^{+}(x)+f^{-}(x)g^{-}(x)\right]dx}$$

while the norm is $\|f\| = <f,f>^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Let $s$ be a positive constant and $A$
the following operator $$A:=\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  -\displaystyle{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}  & \displaystyle{\frac{s}{2}} \\
\\
\displaystyle{\frac{s}{2}} & \displaystyle{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} \\
\end{array}%
\right)$$

with domain $$\mathcal{D}(A) :=\left\{f = \left(%
\begin{array}{c}
  f^{+}(x) \\
  f^{-}(x) \\
\end{array}%
\right)\in\mathcal{H}\,\mbox{such that},\begin{aligned}\,1)&\,f^{+}\,\mbox{and}\,f^{-}\,\mbox{are
absolutely continuous},\\2)&\,f^{+}(-1) = f^{-}(1) =
0\,\,\mbox{and}\\3)&\,Af \in\mathcal{H}\end{aligned}\right\}.$$

My question is: How we can prove that the operator $A$ generates $C_{0}$ semigroup on $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: I think it is possible to prove (via Hille-Yosida Theorem) that $A$ generates a $C_0$-semigroup $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ (such that $\|T(t)\|\leq \mathrm{e}^{st}$) provided that condition $2)$ in domain is replaced by $f^+(-1)=f^+(1)=f^-(-1)=f^-(1)=0$. However, I don't have an answer for the original problem.